# NodeMCU V3 GOT OVERHEATED AND DIED

Tags: esp8266, power, nodemcu, servo, l298n

My NodeMCU V3 got overheated and died. Please help me figure out what i did wrong.

Brief Desrip: Project is an RC Car on ESPNOW Protocol. Transmitter setup have an Arduino Nano to take values from Two analogue joysticks and sends to a NodeMCU through Tx & Rx Pins, which then Transmits the values to the NodeMCU V3 in my Receiver (An RC CAR) over ESPNOW Protocol. Transmitter side is working perfect.

But, the NodeMCU V3 in my Receiver setup has got overheated and Died during a full throttled action. Here I am attaching the wiring diagram of the receiver setup. Please help me figure out whether there is any issues with the wiring.

[image: WIRING DIAGRAM]

Comment: Which part died? The NodeMcu or the motor driver?

Comment: the wiring diagram is not enough ... please provide info about the motor driver module ... it is unclear how the motor driver is getting 5 V ... looks like the motor driver and the servo are pulling power from GPIO D3

Comment: Based on https://lastminuteengineers.com/l298n-dc-stepper-driver-arduino-tutorial/ I'd have (a) ensured that the jumper for the 5v regulator was in place and (b) powered the NodeMCU VIN through the +5v of the motor driver board instead of the 7.4 volts from the battery pack. Have you removed the ENB/+5V jumper ?  What part got hot ? The regulator or the ESP8266 module or what ? Did you simultaneously connect a USB cable to the NodeMCU ?

Comment: Hint: A Power Supply the Arduino is Not!

Comment: @jsotola Motor Driver module is L298N. and D3 is the ENA pin for Speed regulation.

Comment: @PMF The nodeMCU. it got really hot and stopped working. It still gets detected by the pc, but cant upload code, and ESP8266 Module in it gets extremely hot.

Comment: @6v6gt Yes, the 5v reg. jumper is in place. previously i used a buck converter to supply 5v to arduino, but the car's motor was not working with its full potential. Now the car's performance was really good. Why this has happeded? from the information i got, the nodemcu is capable of handling a voltage upto 12v. ... :( i have removed the enb 5v jumper for speed regulation. The nodemcu esp8266 has got hot and died. No didn't connect Usb cable along with other power supply.

Comment: @NonTechGuyinTech  the L298N is one of the components in the motor driver module ... L298N is not the module itself

Comment: @jsotola Could you please tell me what you call an L298N Based motor control module ???

Comment: you just did in your comment ... `L298N Based motor control module` ... the point to my previous comment is that saying `it's an L298N module` does not specify which actual module it is ... a person cannot expect all of the L298N based modules to be the same ... information is needed, about the module you are using

Answer (score 1):

Based on https://lastminuteengineers.com/l298n-dc-stepper-driver-arduino-tutorial/, you have wired your servo incorrectly. The third pin on the bottom blue connector (VSS) is the second input, not the output.

[image: Power wiring diagram of the L298N]

I can only speculate what happened, but I suspect that the servo tried to draw power from the D4 pin which overloaded and fried some internal circuitry of the ESP8266.

Comment: The Arduino Cookbook is a good reference to have. First skim it then zero in on sections that are pertinent to your project.